# Monorepo: Integrating Nestjs into an Angular Workspace

Tags: angular, nestjs

I'm not convinced I need Nx but every resource for Angular monorepo strategy seems to be "learn and setup Nx".

If I have an Angular Workspace with an `app` and a `lib` how could I add a Nestjs server to it so that the server has access to the lib?

1. Main goal is to have direct access to the lib
2. Can the entire repo share the same ts.config, dist etc?
3. Can I avoid Nx?
4. Any better way(s)?

```
repo
  .angular
  vscode
  node_modules
  projects
    app
    lib <-- server needs access
    server <-- will this play well with the Angular workspace?
  .editorconfig
  .gitignore
  angular.json
  package-lock.json
  package.json
  README.md
  tsconfig.json <-- will this apply (and replace) the server's?
```

Answer (score 2):

1.Main goal is to have direct access to the lib

-> You can directly able to access lib by the Main goal is to have direct access to the lib by configuring it in tsconfig.json

In tsconfig.json config

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
  "paths": {
    "@project-name/common-lib": ["projects/lib/common-lib"]
  }
 }
}
```

Call in project like below

```
 import { constants } from '@project-name/common-lib';
```

2.Can the entire repo share the same ts.config, dist etc?

-> Main directory tsconfig.json is base config. Using Nx inside every project there is a tsconfig.json for that project.

->Yes, repo share same dist/ folder.

3.Can I avoid Nx?

-> No, Nx can make managing dependencies and creating and deploying your projects simpler.

4.Any better way(s)?

-> The best choice is Nx. Setting up takes some time. If so, time is saved during another stage of development.

Answer (score 1):

it is not always necessary to use it for a monorepo with Angular and NestJS projects. You can set up your projects without using Nx, but  Nx can make it easier to manage dependencies and build/deploy your projects.
To add a NestJS server to your Angular Workspace,create a new project in the projects directory,like you did for your Angular app and lib.

for ur questions:

2. you can share the same tsconfig.json file and other config files in your projects, but you may need to customize them for each project as needed
3. u can avoid Nx , but it require manual configuration
4. depends on your specific requirements.